# Flexbox login page

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Well i am not a great designer but i am loving this flexbox.
I am making a small login form demo with flexbox using angular 5 material.
I wish to divide my login form into 2 parts.
I am trying to make it responsive fully .
here is what i am looking for : [my login image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0noo.jpg)

So far i have done only this:

**login.component.html**

```
<div class="login-container">
  <mat-card class="mat-elevation-z12">
    <mat-card-content>

    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

**login.component.scss**

```
.login-container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  background: #3f51b5;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  mat-card {
    height: 500px;
    width: 900px;
  }

  mat-card-content {

  }
}
```

Can anybody tell me how I divide this form into 2 parts with the image on the left side block and username/password field on right side of the block?

At the same time how do I make it responsive?

I am not looking for full design but any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/flex-layout#angular-flex-layout

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with angular or am2 as it is. You're apparently asking for help with CSS. Please only use relevant tags.

Comment: It's not obvious which element has the image and which has the username/password. Can you update the HTML to be more clear so we can help?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you'd like to use the `<mat-card>` element to wrap both the image and the form contents. There are many ways to structure this, but the simplest way might be to include two child elements inside `<mat-card>` – one for the form contents (perhaps your current `<mat-card-content>` element), and another for the image. You would then want to apply the flexbox properties to `<mat-card>` rather than `.login-container`.

Here's one possible approach (assuming you want the two child divs to stretch full-width on screens smaller than 600px wide):

First, in your markup:

```
<div class="login-container">
  <mat-card class="mat-elevation-z12">
    <mat-card-image>
        <!-- card image here -->
    </mat-card-image
    <mat-card-content>
        <!-- login form contents here -->
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

And in your SCSS:

```
.login-container {
    mat-card {
        height: 500px;
        width: 900px;
        max-width: 100%; // prevents extending beyond screen width
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }

    mat-card-image,
    mat-card-content {
        flex: 0 1 50%; // sets flex-basis to 50%
    }
}

// media query for responsiveness (adjust 600px as necessary)
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)  {
    .login-container {
        mat-card-image,
        mat-card-content {
            flex: 1 1 100%; // sets flex-basis to 100%
        }
    }
}
```

The `flex: 1 1 100%` properties I'm using are the flex shorthand notation. You can find a thorough explanation of that property here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

I made a quick pen here as a demo:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zRMqvx

Answer (score 0):

- Make a flexbox container by adding a div block or section and setting it to Display: Flex.
- By default, the layout direction will be horizontal and children will stretch vertically
- Add 2 div blocks to the flexbox container and give them the same class.
- Set Sizing: Expand on both divs to make them evenly fill their parent's widths.